# FOL - Predicates without quantifier

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

In First Order Logic if we take the predicate symbol `greater`, then the formula `greater(5,3)` is a well-written formula.

If I write `greater(x,y)`, assuming that $x$ and $y$ are variables is it a no well-written formula ?
Or is the presence of a quantifier that defines $x$, $y$ (or any other letter) as variables ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In first-order logic, you define your language over a signature $\sigma=(P,F,C)$ with a set of predicate symbols $P$, functions symbols $F$ and constant symbols $C$.

Now, for every predicate $p\in P$, you associate with it its *arity* $\mathrm{ar}(p)$, i.e. the number of arguments it takes.

For any predicate symbol $p$ with arity $n$, and any $n$ terms $t_1,\dots,t_n$, $p(t_1,\dots,t_n)$ is a well formed formula.

Terms may be variables, constants or combinations of other terms using function symbols.

---

In your case, you suppose that the associated signature contains a predicate symbol $>$ with arity $2$. $$>(5,3)$$ is thus only a well formed formula if $5,3$ are terms in your first order language, i.e. you have $5,3$ present as constant symbols. However, for any variables $x,y$, $$>(x,y)$$ is always a well formed formula as every variable is a term.

**EDIT:** Don't confuse well-formedness with semantic properties. Well-formedness of a formula asserts that it is part of the associated formal language of first order formulas to a respective signature. This has nothing to do with the property of $>(5,3)$ being valid in some interpretation or not.

Comment: Thanks so much. Can you give me a further clarification about "semantic properties" ? I started studying FOL due to prolog...

Comment: @Koinos Well, the language of first-order logic over a signature consists of all well-formed formulas, however as I've tried to stress in the answer with no attached meaning. Semantics provide meaning to formulas by specifying a model(giving meaning to functions and predicates and constants) and a variable assignment. You may then evaluate a formula with respect to a model and a variable assignment for a truth value. This is just a mere sketch. A good starting point as a book is in my opinion Mathematical Logic by Ebbinghaus, Flum and Thomas.